# How do I create a network bridge programmatically?

Tags: c#, winapi, network-programming, wmi, wdk

I want to create a network bridge between two adapters in windows 7 using c#. I could not find proper documentation for the API to access the components and create the bridge. Please help me to find a solution.

Thanks,
Bhaswanth Gattineni.

Comment: I suspect [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Bindview-ec8f6e0a) is a decent place to start. It doesn't afaik do exactly what you want, but it's a good example to get started with how to deal with the INetCfg APIs.